# Where questions about linux shell commands go?

Tags: discussion, migration, site-recommendation

Does anyone know where I should post questions regarding linux commands such as grep, find, top, ...?  Should they go on Stack Overflow or Server Fault?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81338/migrate-to-super-user-or-unix-linux

Comment: Also, the answers to this question are outdated (from before Ask Ubuntu / Unix and Linux existed).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132659/super-user-versus-unix-and-linux-versus-ask-ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think:

Generic commands ls, grep, etc: [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com)

Network admin commands arp, netstat, etc: [serverfault.com](http://www.serverfault.com)

full on scripting awk, sed, etc: [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 4):

I pretty much agree with the split EBGreen has suggested, however, since there's a pretty big overlap between all the sites on this I would suggest that questions are left on whichever site they originate unless they're very out of place.

Comment: That sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

I think they would be better suited at [superuser.com](http://superuser.com)