# "shell" or "shell-scripting"?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

In reference to the accepted answer on [Where questions about linux shell commands go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16394),
questions about Linux shell scripting should be asked on Stack Overflow and *general* questions about Linux shell should be asked on Super User.

If questions are asked on Stack Overflow, they will be about scripting, so are [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) and [shell-scripting](/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) redundant?

#### Tags:

[shell](/questions/tagged/shell) 2330
[shell-scripting](/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) 1122
[shell](/questions/tagged/shell) && [shell-scripting](/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) 264

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm of the camp where the *language* is called "shell" (well, actually "Bourne shell", "c-shell", "bash"...) but the language group is "shell").

We write [c] and not [c-programming], so we should write [bash] or [shell] and not [bash-scripting] or [shell-scripting].

Comment: +1 same here. I think it does not make sense adding redundant *programming* or *scripting* tags on SO which is meant to answer "questions related to programming".

Comment: can a moderator do a mass retag?

Comment: We may also want to set a synonym.

Comment: I would agree that on StackOverflow the "-scripting" suffix could _perhaps_ be omitted since all questions should be about the programming aspect. However, in the general sense, `shell` is ambiguous IMO. `shell` can refer to the language, but can also refer to other aspects of the shell itself. `shell-scripts` are programs that run within the `shell`.