# Can you ask questions about batch scripting?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, scope, superuser

According to the [about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) page on Stack Overflow, it is a Q&A site for programming. From what I've heard, batch is not a recognized programming language, neither does writing a batch file count as programming. So, is asking questions related to Windows batch still officially accepted at Stack Overflow? Or should they be asked over at Super User?

Comment: Writing a batch file certainly _can_ count as programming. It depends what exactly you're doing.

Comment: I believe that this should be on MSO  rather than MSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2225 questions tagged [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) on SO.  The tag wiki excerpt begins:

> The batch tag is predominantly used for Windows batch file questions. However, every now and then a question related to SQL and batch inserts crops up. Batch files are scripts executed by the Windows command processor (cmd.exe) or, in older times, by the DOS shell (command.com).

There are 383 questions tagged [batch](/questions/tagged/batch) on SU.

Depending on the question, it would probably  be on topic for either.

Related: [Should the batch file programming questions be moved from SO to SF?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46382/should-the-batch-file-programming-questions-be-moved-from-so-to-sf)

Not an identical issue, but in a similar vein: ["shell" or "shell-scripting"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68856/shell-or-shell-scripting)

Answer (score 4):

Batch and shell scripting languages are DSL's. If a batch or shell question is about the mechanics and constructs of the language itself or about consuming an API (like you can do in PowerShell) then it's definitely on-topic for Stack Overflow.

However, if it's a question about a batch or shell script but the real question is about calling a particular OS command line utility then it's possibly better suited on SU or SF.

For example, if someone has a batch or PowerShell script where the real problem is how to use `DISKPART` on Windows then I'd probably push that over to Server Fault. The real question is about how to use `DISKPART`.

Similarly, if it's a bash script and the script isn't working because the usage of a particular Unix tool is incorrect then I'd probably pass that to Unix and Linux.