# Migrate to Super User or Unix & Linux?

Tags: discussion, migration, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Super User versus Unix and Linux versus Ask Ubuntu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132659/super-user-versus-unix-and-linux-versus-ask-ubuntu)

If you see any Linux-related question anywhere on SE, and is in the wrong place, is the choice of destination site arbitrary? Both SU and UL ([unix-SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)) are on-topic and I suppose the final destination is affected by the fact that UL isn't as famous, not to mention that it is not even offered by the migration dialogue?

One thing that has been noted by many is that questions tend to have superior treatment when they reach UL as opposed to when they reach SU, so maybe we should now prefer to send such questions there instead, or at least offer it on that dialogue?

Comment: Don't forget AskUbuntu ;)

Comment: That's going to be one *huge* dialog. Also, I seem to remember the official word on this being that all these questions should go to Super User because they're still on-topic there, even if they would be a better fit on some other niche site. I can't find that duplicate question now, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can flag a question for moderator attention if you believe it is off topic and should be migrated to unix.SE or AskUbuntu.

I try to always migrate linux OS questions to unix.SE and Ubuntu-tagged ones to AU.